# Compiles fine but when it reaches a certain point fails the run. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I'm making a project with extensive code, which is one of the reasons below I won't be able to post it all.
I created a couple of classes, some being friends with each other. Now, one of the options this project has is to be able to create a number of types of terrain and then inserting the object on a vector of a class "Continente", it does so through the loop below.

```
if(linhacomando[1] == "planicie"){
        
        for(int Ploop = 0; Ploop < quantidade; Ploop++){
            
            Planicie P;
            C->AddPlanicie(&P);
            
        }
///more types of terrain with further "ifs" below, but posting it all would be too extensive
```

So by my understanding that creates an object Planicie which is this class.

```
class Planicie{
    
private:
    
    string NomeP;
    const int ResistenciaP = 5;
    int CriarProdutoP;
    const int CriarOuroP = 1;
    const int PontosVitoriaP = 1;
    int ConquistadoP;
    
public:
 
    friend class Continente;
    friend class Imperio;
    friend class Mundo;
    static int NPlanicie;
    Planicie();
    
};
```

and this constructor

```
int Planicie::NPlanicie = 0;

Planicie::Planicie(){
    
    NPlanicie++;
    NomeP = "Planicie" + to_string(NPlanicie);
    CriarProdutoP = 1;
    ConquistadoP = 0;
    cout << NomeP << " criado." << endl;
    
}
```

Then it says to object "C" which was created above(outside of the code posted here) to add this object just created to a vector that C has which is using this function.

```
void Continente::AddPlanicie(Planicie * P){
    
    VPlanicie.push_back(P);
    
}
```

and Continente (C) being this class

```
class Continente{
    
private:
    
    vector <Planicie*> VPlanicie;
    vector <Montanha*> VMontanha;
    vector <Fortaleza*> VFortaleza;
    vector <Mina*> VMina;
    vector <Duna*> VDuna;
    vector <Castelo*> VCastelo;
    
public:
    
    friend class Mundo;
    void AddPlanicie(Planicie * P);
    void AddMontanha(Montanha *M);
    void AddFortaleza(Fortaleza *F);
    void AddMina(Mina *M);
    void AddDuna(Duna *D);
    void AddCastelo(Castelo *C);
    void ShowContinente();
    
};
```

My problem is the following: I have now a command that allows the program to show every terrain created so far, this terrain is stored in the corresponding vectors of Continente, yet it doesn't work. It compiles fine mind you, no errors at all, then I launch it and I can create terrains just fine as well, the moment I enter the command to show what has been created so far it just shuts down. Here is the code.

```
void Continente::ShowContinente(){
    
    for(int loop = 0; loop < this->VPlanicie.size(); loop++){
        
        cout << this->VPlanicie[loop]->NomeP << endl;
        
    }
    
} /// at this moment I'm trying to only show all Planicie Terrains made so far, kinda like a test before adding the rest.
```

and here is the function being called in main

```
void Lista(Continente * C){
   
    C->ShowContinente();
    
}
```

For example, lets say I created 3 Planicie objects. It should have them to [0][1][2] of the VPlanicie vector and then when I ask for it to show me it should print Planicie1, Planicie2, Planicie3.

I understand it's an extensive question, perhaps confusing, but I would love some help.

Comment: Probably undefined behavior somewhere. Time to use a debugger.

Comment: `Planicie P;  C->AddPlanicie(&P);` You store addresses of local variables. You get danginling pointers and UB ensues.

Comment: @churill since it is an object does it work regardless? Because I'm creating the object and storing a pointer to their reference inside the vector?

Comment: @user215272 You create the object, store a pointer to it, then destroy the object. Now the pointer doesn't point to anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(int Ploop = 0; Ploop < quantidade; Ploop++){
        
            Planicie P;
            C->AddPlanicie(&P);
        
        }
```

So each iteration of this loop creates an instance of `Planicie` and passes its address to `AddPlanicie`. Then that object stops existing.

```
void Continente::AddPlanicie(Planicie * P){

    VPlanicie.push_back(P);

}
```

Uh oh, you just added a pointer to an object that's about to stop existing. That pointer will then be useless.

Any time you have a raw pointer to an object, you have to be able to answer the question "where is the object that his points to". And in this case, the object is nowhere, so the pointer points to nothing as soon as the next iteration of the loop executes (or the loop terminates).

Why are you using pointers at all here? Why not use vectors of objects themselves? And if you must use pointers, use pointers that manage the lifetimes of their objects such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I follow, my pointer is basically after a bit pointing to something that has been destroyed, to change that instead of making objects one by one and pointers to them, I should create a vector of objects and then if I ever need to add more objects at a later iteration just add them to that vector as well?

Comment: @user215272 You can't add an object to a vector. Either an object is in a vector or it isn't. (The same is true of an array. If `i` is an integer with value 3 that's not in a vector or array, if you "add `i` to the vector/array" what you'll actually do is add the value 3 to the vector/array.)

Comment: @user215272 But you can create a vector that holds instances of your class and you can create new instances in the vector. But you can't literally put an existing object into the vector or take an object out of the vector -- you'd have to create a new object to do that.

Comment: @user215272 If `i` is 3 then you "add `i` to the vector" and then set `i` to 4, the vector will still contain the value 3 because `i` itself isn't in the vector. All you did was add a new object with the same value as `i`. If you need to literally put objects into and out of the vector, then the vector has to contain some kind of pointer to that object, ideally `std::unique_ptr<>`.

Comment: so as an example if I do vector<test*> MyVector. I can store pointers to objects of the type test, however, if I create test objects on some function by doing Test test1, and so on, once I leave the function the objects get destroyed and therefore MyVector pointers are pointing to nothing, correct?

Comment: @user215272 Correct. You can create objects with `new` that will live until you `delete` them and store those in the vector, but *do* *not* *do* *that*. If you want the vector to logically own the objects but really do need to add or remove actual objects from the vector, then use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Alright sorry to keep bothering but just to be clear. If I need the vector to store a copy of the object, and then change that copy members if needed is that possible? I don't really need the original object I just need to: "Create the object and then tell the vector, store something exactly equal to this that you can alter later."

Comment: The just use `std::vector<type>`. Then the vector will behave like an array except you can change its size as needed.